# Getting the user ID of the created user

Tags: angularjs, object, firebase, angularfire

I'm using angularfire as backend in my angular app but I need help when it comes to extracting the user ID **of the last account that has just been created.**

Below is an image from the "login and auth" section in the database, this is where the user ID resides.

[image: userid image]

This is the function that creates a new user, using the email and password that the user enters via a registration form. (`user` is an object that comes from a validation function that gets run before this one).

```
$scope.registerNewUser = function(user) {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://pie-shop.firebaseio.com/");
        ref.createUser({
            email    : user.email,
            password : user.password
        }, function(error) {
            if (error === null) {
                $('#error-message').show().html('Success!').css({color: 'limegreen'});
            }
            else {
                $('#error-message').show()
                .html('Something went wrong when trying to create your account, please try again later')
                .css({color: 'red'});
            } 
        });
},
$scope.storeUserInfo = function(user, userID) {

    var newUser = new Firebase('https://pie-shop.firebaseio.com/' + userID);
}
```

So what I need to do is, preferably in the `function(error)` if statement, is get the user ID of the newly created account and call the `storeUserInfo` function with the user ID as an argument so that I can use it to store the other information that the user have entered.

By simply using `$push` to store the information in the database wouldn't allow me to match the user ID with the `key` to get the corresponding information since Firebase generates **unique keys** when pushing data into the database. (Or is there a clever way even by using push? Let me know if that's the case).

Comment: don't do DOM manipulation in the the controller!

Comment: I will change that later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/createuser.html) on `createUser`:

> onComplete *Function*
>
> > A callback function that will be called when the user account has been created. On failure, the first argument will be an Error object indicating the failure, with a machine-readable code attribute. On success, the first argument will be null, and **the second argument will be an object containing attributes of the newly-created user, including the uid**.

(emphasis mine)

So, do this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://pie-shop.firebaseio.com/");
ref.createUser({
    email    : user.email,
    password : user.password
}, function(error, user) {
    if (error === null) {
        console.log(user);
    }
    else {
        // deal with error
    } 
});
```

Comment: Make sure you're on the latest SDK. This argument was added circa 2.1.0.

Comment: @Kato thanks for that comment, was on 2.0.4 so didn't work at first but now it does :)

Answer (score 0):

In this [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/learn-to-build-realtime-webapps/#authenticating-users-with-a-service) (section: Authenticating users with a service) you gonna do this. You register a user and log him in instantly. The user-object is then stored in `$scope.user`. You are able to get the user id from firebase with `$scope.user.userId` (or console.log it to find the correct value). Hope it helps. By the way: Great tutorial for learning angular and firebase.

Comment: bookmarked the tutorial for whenever I get the time to go through it, thanks :)